# jquery clone problem

Tags: jquery, clone

Can anyone tell me how can i clone an element and then change its id.
Can anyone provide me with some sample code.
i want to generate a clone with a different id the code given below.

```
$("#Normal_Tag1_div").draggable({
            helper:'clone',
            revert: 'invalid'
            });
```

Comment: if the element you are cloning is already draggable then you need to use clone(false) so the events do not get copied over.
Would help if you could paste your whole page/script

Answer (score 3):

Your question and comment do not make things very clear however I have revised my answer.

A working demo of cloning an element, renaming the id and initializing the draggable is show [here](http://pastebin.me/d82f590b7bc35644aaa53e9dff66a37f).

You cant clone the element if you have already initialized the draggable as the new element when dragged will drag the old element as show [here](http://pastebin.me/a7b894056130186423c9c53aa865dbe0)

```
    $("#draggable").clone()
                   .attr('id', 'newDrag')

   $('#draggable, #newDrag').draggable();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#Normal_Tag1_div").clone().attr("id", "newId")
  .draggable({ helper:'clone', revert: 'invalid' });
```

Comment: But it is not working.
If i write the eaxct code the element stops being draggable.
I have created this
$("#Normal_Tag1_div").draggable({ helper:'clone', revert: 'invalid' });
draggable node of which i want to create a  clone so that if i want to access this id from somewhere else i can.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty Old Post, but this one work for me :

```
$('#staveID').draggable(
    {
        helper: "clone"
    }
)   
.bind('drag', function(event, ui){
       $("#staveID:last-child").attr("id", "currentStave");
});
```